Is it true that some cabover trucks are designed to allow the cab to detach in a crash to protect the driver?
On a YouTube video showing crash tests between trucks and bollards where the cab tumbled over top of the bollard and continued for quite a distance a comment claimed that:

the cab braking [sic] of [sic] the truck is for safety of the driver. they are designed to snap of [sic] when in a collision like that

Is there any basis to this?

What does the truck manufacturer say? This is something they would mention re marketing and driver safety.

why would it be false?

The occupant of that cab would be in for a very rough ride, broken arms legs and quite possibly neck. Rolling people around is a great way of breaking them.

Unless this is a standard test (I doubt it) then no, the truck won't be designed for it.
